# VSCode PHP debug ext can not connect to DBGp proxy server

Tags: vscode-extensions, xdebug

- PHP version: v8.1.18
- Xdebug version: 3.2.0
- web server: Homestead on remote 192.168.10.10
- DBGp proxy server runs on local Windows 10:

```
./dbgpProxy.exe -i 127.0.0.1:9001 -s 0.0.0.0:9003
```

- xdebug.ini

```ini
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host = 192.168.10.1
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger
xdebug.trigger_value = ''
```

- PHP debug launch.json

```json
{
    "name": "DBGp Proxy",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "pathMappings": {
        "/home/vagrant/laravel10": "D:\\workspace\\laravel10"
    },
    "proxy": {
        "enable": true,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 9001,
        "key": "vsc",
        "allowMultipleSessions": false
    }
}
```

- DBGp proxy server log:

```text
06:46:36.326 [info] [server] Start new server connection from 192.168.10.10:36512
06:46:36.327 [info] [proxy-client] [vsc] Could not find IDE connection for IDE Key 'vsc'
06:46:36.331 [warn] [server] Handler response error: Error reading response: Error reading length: EOF
06:46:36.332 [info] [server] Closing server connection from 192.168.10.10:36512
```

- Everything is OK when using PhpStorm:

```text
07:03:13.986 [info] [server] Start new server connection from 192.168.10.10:37788
07:03:13.987 [info] [proxy-client] [PHPSTORM] Found connection for IDE Key 'PHPSTORM': 127.0.0.1:9000
07:03:13.991 [info] [proxy-client] [PHPSTORM] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000
07:03:13.994 [info] [proxy-client] [PHPSTORM] IDE connected
07:03:13.996 [info] [proxy-client] [PHPSTORM] Init forwarded, start pipe
```

I can not find something like `Register IDE` in VSCode. How to connect VSCode IDE client to DBGp Proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It registers once you click on the green arrow next to "Listen for Xdebug".

Similar to when you click on the little "Start Listening For PHP Debug Connections" in PhpStorm.

As it just happens, I recorded a video yesterday to explain it: https://youtu.be/_3RkGZK-UC8

I'll follow up with an article version.

Comment: After clicking the start debug button, there is nothing showed up in the debug console panel.  I suspect there is something wrong on the IDE side. I just found there are two different PHP debug extensions installed in my vscode .They must be conflict so the function is broken down. I uninstalled another one and everything gets ok. Thanks for the video, it is really helpful for new comers for using xdebug with DBGp proxy.